# How to merge object in IE 11

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-11

I have the following array of object:

```
Objs[0] = {Name : "ABC"};
Objs[1] = {Roll : 123}
```

I'm trying to make it as the following:

```
Objs {
  Name : "ABC",
  Roll : 123
}
```

I attempted to make it with the following code:

```
var Objs = [{
  Name: "ABC"
}, {
  Roll: 123
}];

console.log(
  Object.assign.apply(null, [{}].concat(Objs)) // 1
)
or 

console.log(
  Object.assign({}, ...Objs) // 2
)
```

The problem is that this is not working in IE 11.

I get the errors:

> Error for 1 : Unable to get property 'on' of undefined or null reference
>
> Error for 2 : Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

Any suggestions on how I should merge the object in IE 11?

Comment: As @Nina Scholz said, IE doesn't support Object.assing() hence you can write the function as she suggested or use polyfill to add that functionality. You can also use babel-polifill at the global level.

Comment: [MDN Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

Comment: @Ram why does the MDN page then state IE 10 in compatibility? seems to be a mistake ...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

IE11 does not support [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility).

You could iterate the array and the keys and take the values as new property of the result object.

```js
var objs = [{ Name: "ABC" }, { Roll: 123 }],
    result =  objs.reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            r[k] = o[k];
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I noticed that this does not work on properties that are arrays, in IE 11. I added a check for arrays and use .concat() in my use case. `if (Object.prototype.toString.call(o[k]) === "[object Array]")) r[k] = (r[k] || []).concat(o[k])` and then else the line you have in the forEach.

Comment: @Calle, does it work now? you could use a simple check and an inline push, like `(r[k] = r[k] || []).push(o[k])`.

Comment: depends on the outcome you are looking for, I suppose.  I guess push is much faster, as long as adding at the end is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 57):

You can use jQuery method [$.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) which work in IE 11.

```js
var object = {name: 'John', surname: 'Rowland'};
var newObject = $.extend({}, object);

newObject.age = '30';

console.log(object);
console.log(newObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can also directly put `{age: 30}` as the first parameter instead of adding it afterwards: `var newObject = $.extend({age: 30}, object};`

Comment: @DuncanLuk in this scenario, yes, but it might have an undesired effect if `object` had an `age` in it.

Comment: Just add `{ age: 30 }` to the end of the parameter list: `var newObject = $.extend({}, object, { age: 30 }};` to override any potentially existing `age` property in `object`.

Answer (score 15):

Install:

```
npm i -s babel-polyfill
```

And at the top of entry **index.js** file add:

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
```

This will solve some issues that Babel did not. **Object.assign** is one of them.

> This means you can use new built-ins like Promise or WeakMap, static
>   methods like Array.from or Object.assign, instance methods like
>   Array.prototype.includes, and generator functions (provided you use
>   the regenerator plugin). The polyfill adds to the global scope as well
>   as native prototypes like String in order to do this.

For the end, you will need to decide whether you want to use the whole **babel-polyfill** (which is around 50kb minimized) or to use only what you need through individual polyfills, ie. **es6-promise** for Promises.

Answer (score 5):

I think best thing to do, if you are using lodash util library in your project, is lodash's **assign** method, which works same as Object.prototype.assign for all browsers, including IE (at least IE11): https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign

If you are not using lodash yet, consider it. It has many util functions which works perfectly fine on all browsers, either in JavaScript, TypeScript and NodeJS (tested by myself, but probably it supports other JS connected technologies as well). Personally I include lodash to all my javascript connected projects

Comment: Nice, can't beat some Lodash

Answer (score 4):

Use a polyfill like this; [Ref: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

```
 if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  // Must be writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true
  Object.defineProperty(Object, "assign", {
    value: function assign(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
      'use strict';
      if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);

      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[index];

        if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
          for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
            // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
              to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}
```

Comment: this doesn't support symbol property 'coz ie11 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TypeScript, try to replace `Object.assign({}, ...Objs)` to `{...Objs};` the browser will automatically replace it to `__assign({}, Objs);` and this notacion works in IE11.

Comment: I can confirm this works on IE11 and Edge. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @vladatr, in case you're using Wepack:

In your webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.js")],
  .
  .
```

In my entry point `src/index.js` file:

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

Answer (score 0):

This javascript only solution works in IE. Loop through the array, and within that loop through each key in the object and add it to a new object. The new object contains the data you want.

```js
var Objs = [];
Objs[0] = {Name : "ABC"};
Objs[1] = {Roll : 123};

console.log(Objs);

var newObject = {};

for(var i=0; i<Objs.length; i++) {

    for(var key in Objs[i]) {
        if(! Objs[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
            continue;

        newObject[key] = Objs[i][key];
    }
}

console.log(newObject);
```

If you need to you can assign the newObject to your array variable `Objs = newObject`

Answer (score -1):

If you use TypeScript you can use

```
let newObject = {
    ...existingObject
}
```

This creates a shallow copy of the existing object.

Comment: The spread operator has nothing to do with TypeScript. It's a JavaScript feature, available from ES6 onwards.

Comment: @LiranH correct, but if you use TypeScript you can use it even if your target browser doesn't support ES6.

Comment: Again, nothing to do with TypeScript, it's the transpiler (e.g. Babel) that takes care of that. You can be writing in JS ES2020 for example, and the transpiler would transpile it to ES5.

Answer (score -1):

Even with babel:

```
const newObj = Object.assign({}, myOtherObject)
```

was destroying us in IE11.

We changed it to:

```
const newObj = { ...myOtherObject }
```

and that worked in conjunction with babel.

Comment: the reason why babel on its own doesnt make Object.assign work in ie11 is becuase its not a language construct that can be `transpiled` down. Its a function within the Object type meaning it needs to be polyfilled.
Babel can do this but its a more complex build and config process See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins