# Babel Preset does not provide support on IE11 for Object.assign - "Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'"

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I am using **babel-preset-env version - 1.6.1** for my react app, i am getting a error on IE :- *Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'*
[image]

this is my **.babelrc** :-

```
{
"presets": [
    "react",
    [
        "env",
        {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": [
                    "last 1 versions",
                    "ie >= 11"
                ]
            },
            "debug": true,
            "modules": "commonjs"
        }
    ]
],
"env": {
    "test": {
        "presets": [
            [
                "babel-preset-env",
                "react"
            ]
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "transform-object-rest-spread",
            "transform-class-properties",
            "transform-runtime",
            "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node",
            "array-includes",
            "url-search-params-polyfill",
            "transform-object-assign"
        ]
    }
},
"plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-runtime",
    "array-includes",
    "url-search-params-polyfill",
    "transform-object-assign"
]
```

}

i tried these polyfills :-

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-object-assign

but it didn't work

i am using syntax:-

```
let a = Object.assign({},obj);
```

everywhere in my project

i need a polyfill that would work for my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge object in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091600/how-to-merge-object-in-ie-11)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need [Babel Polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Either import it in your entry JS file, or use Webpack.

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

or in `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./app/main"]
}
```

**NOTE : `babel-polyfill` Should be imported on very top else It will not work**

Comment: That **NOTE** there is very important!

Comment: or if you have a multipage app and added react later into legacy code like I did you can include before any of your bundles within either <head> or <body> tags a reference to the script src for the babel polyfill - either link to a cdn that has it or make a local copy to reference

Answer (score 26):

### Babel Polyfill is outdated as of Babel 7.4.0

([Source](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill))

Please use core-js instead.

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

Or with Webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime", "./app/main"]
}
```

In my case the above webpack config **did not work!** because I was also lacking a promise polyfill. This is the webpack.config I ended up using:

```
entry: { 'main': ['core-js/fn/promise', 'core-js/stable/object/assign', './wwwroot/src/app.js'] },
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for our problem with IE11. Question: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#usage-in-node-browserify-webpack
"When used alongside @babel/preset-env,

If useBuiltIns: 'usage' is specified in .babelrc then do not include @babel/polyfill in either webpack.config.js entry array nor source. Note, @babel/polyfill still needs to be installed."

How come core-js has to be in the entry array for IE11?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But now in 2020, after making below changes, it is working. entry: { 'main': ['core-js-pure/stable/promise', 'core-js/stable/object/assign', './wwwroot/src/app.js'] },

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me both in development and production!